# Associate a Custom Filename with RSpec in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I'm using RSpec to write some unit tests for a function I have in the same file. To keep everything consistent, I want to name every file `challenge.rb`. If this case, Ruby Mine doesn't show run button if the file doesn't end with `*_spec.rb`, `*_test.rb`, or etc. Also, `rspec` command in Terminal shows no tests were found.

Any way to associate a custom filename with RSpec that works on Ruby Mine, or even VS Code and I can share the configuration with Git, so everyone can pull the settings?

Answer (score 0):

The current logic in RubyMine is that it takes into account the file's name, and at the moment it does not support any customization. So could you please submit your request as feature one on the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY